# How get info about few posts on facebook?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to fetch information about likes, comments and etc. from only one post object and here's the request code I send.

Example of my requests:

class StatsSN:
    def **init**(self, fb_post_id, fb_token):
        self.fb_post_id = fb_post_id
        self.fb_token = fb_token

```
def req_stats(self, url_method):
    req = requests.get(url_method)
    if req.status_code != 200:
        # return req.json().get('error')
        # return 'error'
        log.info('FB_Statistics: %s' % req.json())
        return -1
    return req.json().get('summary').get('total_count')

def fb_likes(self):
    url_method = fb_api_url + '%s/likes?summary=true&access_token=%s' % (self.fb_post_id, self.fb_token)
    return self.req_stats(url_method)

def fb_reactions(self):
    url_method = fb_api_url + '%s/reactions?summary=total_count&access_token=%s' % (self.fb_post_id, self.fb_token)
    return self.req_stats(url_method)

def fb_comments(self):
    url_method = fb_api_url + '%s/comments?summary=true&access_token=%s' % (self.fb_post_id, self.fb_token)
    return self.req_stats(url_method)

def fb_sharedposts(self):
    url_method = fb_api_url + '%s/sharedposts?access_token=%s' % (self.fb_post_id, self.fb_token)
    req = requests.get(url_method)
    if req.status_code != 200:
        log.info('FB_Statistics: %s' % req.json())
        return -1
    return len(req.json().get('data'))

def fb_stats(self):
    fb_likes, fb_reactions, fb_comments, fb_sharedposts = self.fb_likes(), self.fb_reactions(), self.fb_comments(), \
                                                          self.fb_sharedposts()
    return int(fb_likes), int(fb_reactions), int(fb_comments), int(fb_sharedposts)
```

Is there a method in the Graph API to get info about few posts in one request?

Comment: You need to start by converting this to Field Expansion syntax (instead of `foo/likes`, it becomes `foo?fields=likes`), then you can apply this to either a feed of posts, or supply multiple independent post ids via the `ids` parameter. (And since I can feel _do you have an example_ coming next, please go read the documentation on basic API usage if you are not familiar with the mentioned stuff.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by sending a batch request; If you only need public data, a normal page token is good enough. However if you need private information, you will need a specific page token of the page post you want to get the metrics of.

As the metrics you are referring to are public, you should be able to send a GET request with following syntax:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/?fields=id,comments.limit(0).summary(true),shares,reactions.limit(0).summary(true)&ids=STATUS_ID1,STATUS_ID2,STATUS_ID3,...,STATUS_ID50&access_token=PAGE_TOKEN
```

You can request up to 50 status id's in one call.

```
limit(0).summary(true)
```

This part you need to add with comments and reactions as it is the best practice to retrieve the total amount of comments/reactions.

Comment: Can i add /insights/ to this requests and see views of all posts?

Comment: No, that won't work. `/insights` uses other metrics which you can find in the [manual](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/insights). However you can use the same syntax to scrape up to 50 status_ids in one call.